# Use Pull Request to merge EAP files (Enterprise Architect)

Tags: git, jenkins, github, enterprise-architect, pull-request

I have a request to use GitHub Pull Request in a git repo which is continuously developing in a single binary file (EAP model from Enterprise Architect) into a master branch.

By the time a pull request is open, it triggers Jenkins and it should use an special merging tool in order to merge EAP files, but how to integrate such tool with GitHub Pull Request?

What do you recommend me to do for such request? any idea?

As far as I know, Pull Request will merge using git only right?

Comment: Voted to close this as off-topic. However, merging UML models is just a PITA. No matter which approach you take. You might look at LieberLieber's LemonTree which is targeting towards what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.eap file is a jet (MS-Access) database file.

There are no merge tools to merge .eap files. EA's version control system relies on xmi files.

So basically you should be using the built-in xmi-based mechanism instead of trying to merge binary files.

Answer (score 0):

I am affilated with LieberLieber and LemonTree is a commercial solution to use EA Models with Git

If you enhance your expierence with LemonTree 3.3+ and LemonTree.Automation you can do true pull request style workflows with Enterpirse Archtiect (.eap,.eapx, .qea,.qeax) files.

Here is a Repo with Github Actions that showcases some of the stuff ;)

https://github.com/LieberLieber/LemonTree.Automation.Workflows

e.g check out this pull request:
https://github.com/LieberLieber/LemonTree.Automation.Workflows/pull/72

The session files might be expired - but they will load automaticaly in LT 3.3+

Comment: You should disclose the fact that you are affiliated with this commercial product, or this answer will be deleted by the community.